# Terminal Blank Screen after removing zsh

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

I get blank screen on terminal after removing zsh! I can basically do nothing.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Can you login on tty1?

Comment: Can you get a tty by pressing `CTRL+ALT+F1`? If yes, you can try to run `chsh` there and try to change your default shell.

Comment: I can't login in tty! I get it but can't login to any instant including 1-6!

Comment: The problem is actually in the .zshrc which persist to call zsh which was uninstall. I tried to do `source ~/.bashrc` which did not work. A work around was to install zsh in xterm and change default then uninstall it. sounds dum but yeah did the job!

Answer (score 5):

Firstly try to run Xterm which is another terminal emulator with minimal settings by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> then type:

```
xterm -e sh
```

It'll open Xterm , Then try to run the command to make bash as your default

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Comment: It says I can change shell for "my user" and su myuser prompt an zsh error `Cannot execute /usr/bin/zsh` which was the reason why I uninstalled zsh in the first place.

Comment: @OdinRW You can change it or you can't change it? If you can, then do it. It should not ask you anything about zsh after that any more. I think I'm not understanding your comment correctly...

Comment: @ByteCommander No I can't change it. It says I may not change shell for that user, and I can't change user because it throws back an error saying `/usr/bin/zsh is not found`

Comment: It seems your zsh  was in /usr/bin   and still searching for that, so try this  chsh -s /usr/bin/bash

Comment: You should be able to change your own user's shell though. As who are you logged in? Is it an admin or normal user? Who's shell do you want to change?

Comment: @ByteCommander so `echo $(logname)` returns my user and I use sudo. I restarted and tried again it did not return any error but still I get the blank screen! I restarted after `chsh -s /bin/zsh`

Comment: have you tried               chsh -s /usr/bin/bash

Comment: Yes dude I did. The problem is actually in the .zshrc which persist to call zsh which was uninstall. I tried to do `source ~/.bashrc` which did not work. A work around was to install zsh in xterm and change default then uninstall it. sounds dum but yeah did the job!

Comment: @OdinRW Would you please write a short answer to your own question and explain how you solved it for future readers? Thank you!

Comment: @ByteCommander just did :) thanks guys you are awesome!

Comment: @OdinRW good to know , no problem any time!

Answer (score 5):

First run Xterm and install zsh

```
xterm -e sh
sudo apt-get install zsh
```

Then change default to bash

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Then remove zsh! This is only a workaround as zsh was always loaded as a default shell and I could not source using `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks and upvoted. Please note that you can and should also accept your own answer, however the system forces a delay of two days to allow this.